# How to read a string into a vector of strings or an integer into a vector of integers

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a few problems with some code I am writing for research. I am having to learn C++ as  I go unfortunately because I do not have enough time to actually sit down and read books. I have some background in Java.

I would like to take a read a string into a vector of strings.

```
for (int i=0; i<numFiles; i++){ //while "i" is less than the number of files

    numSignalFileBits(signalFile); // call the method "numSignalFileBits" on "signalFiles"
    numBackgroundFileBits(backgroundFile); // call the method "numBackgroundFileBits" on "backgroundFile"

    signalFileSize >> signalFileSizes;
    backgroundFileSize >> backgroundFileSizes;

    fileSplitting(signalFile, backgroundFile);

    signalFileExtension >> signalFileExtensions;
    backgroundFileExtension >> backgroundFileExtensions;

    }

    signalFileSizes.push_back(signalFileSize); // add the size of the file to the end of the vector
    backgroundFileSizes.push_back(backgroundFileSize); // add the size of the file to the end of the vector
```

This is what I have written for that particular part of the program. I get an error messages saying "Invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'vector ') and "Invalid operands to binary expression ('string' and vector '') " I was wondering if somebody could explain what this message meant. I didn't fully understand it when I searched it on google.

The second issue is a method I am writing for binary addition. Each of the strings is a file, which will contain bits. I want to take the following bits and perform subtraction on them. This is the code I have written for that.

```
int fileAddition (int numFiles, string signalFile, string backgroundFile){
    for(int i=0; i<numsignalFileBits; i++){
         sum[numSignalFileBits] = 0;
        sum[i] = (singalFile[i] + 1) + ~ backgroundFile[i];

}

return sum[i];
}
```

I was wondering if this was an okay way to subtract the bits in the files to determine the sum.

Comment: You should move your second, unrelated question about binary addition into a separate SO question.  (Well, taking more time to look at it, you  should be telling us which of your test cases failed and what you don't understand about that).

Comment: Have you actually tried running this?  There's not enough code to even understand what you're trying to accomplish with the first part, but the second part references `i` outside the scope it is defined in (the for loop).  This will not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'vector ') and "Invalid operands to binary expression ('string' and vector '') " I was wondering if somebody could explain what this message meant.

You're doing this:

```
signalFileSize >> signalFileSizes;
```

The binary operator `>>` does not add values to `vector`: use `push_back`.